# How to setup dependent parallel tasks in groovy pipeline to the same slave

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I have 3 Tasks that need to be in 3 pipelines that will run such that Task 1 & 2 run in parallel. 
 Task 1 needs to run in the background, silently (**How to set this up?**) 
 Task 2 is the worker and 
Task 3 triggers after Task 2 completed. 
 Task 1 which was running in the background, needs to be terminated when Task 2 completes so that Task 3 can be triggered.  (**Not sure how to set this up.**)
 In this scenario, task 1 writes to files. Will the termination of Task 1 causes issues if it is writing to a file when receiving a termination from Jenkins?
Any help to this is greatly appreciated.

```
node ("mach12") {
parallel(
    "Monitors":{               // <-Terminate this after 'Assorted Tasks' ends.
       stage("Task1"){
        dir('C:\\Tasks\\StatsMonitor') {
             retCode = (powershell(returnStdout: true, script: 'return Invoke-Expression -Command \" .\\myMonitor.exe ' + P1 +' \"'))
        }
      }
    },

   "Assorted Tasks" :{
      stage("Task2"){
      //Multiple other exe's called here.
      }
   }, failFast: true) 

stage("Task3"){
    //assorted tasks here.
}
}
```